# Can I use JVM to implementing high loaded TCP/IP single-machine server? What about GC settings?

Tags: java, sockets, garbage-collection, jvm

I’m trying to implement high loaded TCP/IP single-machine server.

I’ve several limitations:

1. Server must support up to 8 connections.
2. Each connection must receive up to 25 Megabytes per second. I think average summary speed of all connections - 90% of time - will be about 100 Megabytes per second, but system must stable work in worst case too.
3. I need to extract messages from network input and split it to messages (my classes). Messages vary from hundreds bytes to 10-15 Megabytes. Messages are very simple: several fields and – in case of big messages - array of bytes.
4. I need to register (write to a very big plain file) data from each connection. It’s guaranteed that disk system can write at such speed. I’ll use several enterprise-class SSDs.
5. There is process which processes data after writing to disk. After some time data will be deleted. I.e. I need about 50% of processor resources.
6. Server must work 24*7*365.
7. Server must work on commodity-class hardware (8Gb RAM, i7 (i5 preferable) processor). My project have restrictions with size of hardware (very small box, low heat and low power consumption) and price. Unfortunately, I can’t change it if you propose.

Is here anyone who implemented high loaded systems on commodity software with JVM? As I know, operations system must bufferize network input, so GC delays don’t matter in such situation, isn’t it? What can I read about JVM (GC)?

Meybe it’s not high load system. You are welcome to discuss

Comment: I don't see any reason why this isn't possible in Java. However, if you are familiar with C or C++ and you have a compiler exactly for your server, then maybe C or C++ is the better choice. But Java with its JustInTime (JIT) compilation can also optimize for your processor and instruction set at runtime, which in C/C++ is only possible if you have a compiler exactly for the server's CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Language / Runtime is the least of your worries:

You aren't going to get `200MB` a second over a single network interface, not even a `1Gb` one. You will need at least 2 `1Gb` network interfaces bonded on both ends to be able to push anything near that speed through commodity hardware. `100MB` per second isn't even feasible on a `1Gb` interface. That would be approximately `0.8Gb` a second. Well over the real world sustained rate of about `0.6Gb` I see on a single connection that has jumbo frames enabled even. And then you have no overhead for bursts.

This is I/O bound at the hardware level, software is the least of your worries. And these interfaces need to support `Jumbo Frames` on both ends and all the switches, routers and other hardware in between.

[Ethernet Maximum Rates, Generation, Capturing & Monitoring](http://wiki.networksecuritytoolkit.org/nstwiki/index.php/LAN_Ethernet_Maximum_Rates,_Generation,_Capturing_%26_Monitoring)

#### Software:

What you propose can be written in any reasonably peformance high level language. Java, Python, Ruby, Erlang or .Net would all be capable. Your hardware constraints are what you are not going to be able to over come.

#### Hardware:

I would say you are going to be hard pressed to get that kind of throughput on a single commodity hardware machine. Regardless of the class of SSD, a dedicated RAID controller is most likely the only way you are going to get the I/O you want.

Comment: Jarrod, what about several network cards, is it possible to achieve 200 Megabytes per second speed? As I understand, I need different routers. I've 8 devices (each still can emit 25 Megabytes per second). How can I connect them to my computer? Maybe 2 routers, each for 4 devices?

Comment: @engineer I wouldn't assume multiple routers will make any difference. Can you explain how using more than one router would help?

Comment: @engineer If you stick enough network cards there, disk output will become a problem, if you solve that, then the load on the internal bus. If you solve that, power consumption will be your next issue. In other words: this task seems too big for the hardware you need. Compared to that, any software issues are negligible.

Comment: Peter Lawrey, 2 routers, each connected to one network card

Comment: you don't need routers, you need a switch that supports jumbo frames and network interfaces that support the same size jumbo frames, there is a fundamental difference between a router and a switch.

Comment: Jarrod, I don't understand: standard cable can transmit up to 1 Gigabit per second hence I need 2 cables connected with my computer and each cable must be connected with a router/switch and each router/switch must be connected with 4 devices. In such case what is the difference between a router and a switch?

Comment: if you don't know the difference between a router and a switch this is probably way above your head already. Never conflate Gb with MB either, they aren't the same in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> Server must support up to 8 connections.

I can't imagine how this would be a problem. You can handle thousands, if not tens of thousands of connection with Java.

> Each connection must receive up to 25 Megabytes per second. I think average summary speed of all connections - 90% of time - will be about 100 Megabytes per second, but system must stable work in worst case too.

This means you need at least a 1 Gb/s connection.  Java can handle this rate with one thread.

Note: 100 MB/s is about 8 TB/day.  You will have to find way to minimise disk usage if you plan to use SSD.

> Server must work on commodity-class hardware (8Gb RAM, i7 (i5 preferable) processor). My project have restrictions with size of hardware (very small box, low heat and low power consumption) and price. Unfortunately, I can’t change it if you propose.

I have no idea why you would buy multiple enterprise SSD and very buy on 8 GB (I assume you mean Giga-byte not Gb = Giga-bit) My 8 year son had 8 GB for his games PC 18 months ago.  Not sure why you would by an i5 for a performance system either. I would get an i7 if not a Xeon. Not because it can't be done using i5, but because you will cost far more in development time than you will save in hardware.

The rest seems entirely achievable.

> Is here anyone who implemented high loaded systems on commodity software with JVM?

Many have, it depends on what you are trying to do.

> As I know, operations system must bufferize network input, so GC delays don’t matter in such situation, isn’t it?

Network buffers don't make any difference to GCs.  They can help if you have very bursty behaviour, but if you only need 1 Gb/s I wouldn't worry about it so much.

The most important thing to do is to manage your allocaton rate by reducing usage.  A memory profiler can help you do that.

> What can I read about JVM (GC)?

I spend your time reducing the need for GC, esp since you have so little memory.  Most servers these days have well over 32 GB e.g. 256 GB to 4 TB.  It sounds like your main problem will be relatively high data rates for a small amount of memory.  This is fine if the work you do on each message is simple, but without more information, I would start with at least 64 GB.